# Reload .Net configuration from AWS Secrets Manager

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, appsettings, aws-secrets-manager

I want to reload .Net configurations from AWS. It loads correctly on startup and reloads as it should using a periodic timer and checking for changes in AWS. But how can I do this without a timer, by adding a Reload() function and calling it from another service?

This is the tutorial I used for loading the configurations and reloading using timer: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/modernizing-with-aws/how-to-load-net-configuration-from-aws-secrets-manager/

I tried injecting AmazonSecretsManagerConfigurationProvider to the service where I want to reload my configurations and calling Reload(), but the configurations doesn't update. And I am using IOptionsSnapshot for my configurations/options. Here is my Reload function in the provider:

```
public void Reload()
    {
        Load();

        OnReload();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

By considering you had made the basic setup on how using the custom configuration provider with AWS Secrets. To Reload on Runtime we can have a class for the same.

```
public class AwsCustomReloader
{
    private readonly IConfigurationRoot _configRoot;//configuration root to help with all the available providers
    public AwsCustomReloader(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configRoot = (IConfigurationRoot) configuration;
    }

    public void ReloadAWSSecretData()
    {
        //get the provider of type you need to Re-Load
        var _provider = _configRoot.Providers.FirstOrDefault(provider => provider.GetType() == typeof(AWSSecretConfigProvider));
        _provider.Load();//loading again with the root instance(Re-Load)
    }
}
```

The above snippet worked for me fine while using IOptionsSnapshot

Answer (score 0):

*"But how can I do this without a timer"*

Pseudocode

```cs
public class ConfigFetcher
{

    private datetime _lastFetched;
    private const int _lifespan = 10; // min
    private object _lock = new object();    
    private string _config = null;
 
    private string Fetch()
    {
        if (_config == null || DateTime.Now > _lastFetched.AddMinutes(_lifespan))
        {
            lock(_lock)
            {
                if (_config == null || DateTime.Now > _lastFetched.AddMinutes(_lifespan))
                {
                    // Make your AWS call to load the secret 
                    _config  = ......
                    _lastFetched = datetime.Now;
                }
            }
        }

        return _config;

    }
}
```

This code will get you config on-demand and with refresh. Where do you use it - in web api, windows app or console app - it does not matter. You keep this class as singleton in your dependency injection or just make singleton from it.

Also, you can look into AWS package "Secret Manager Cache" [which can do refreshing for you](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/retrieving-secrets_cache-net-SecretsManagerCache.html)